# Remove -SNAPSHOT from project version in pom

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin, versions-maven-plugin

I have a pom with the following GAV

```
<groupId>com.company.services</groupId>
<artifactId>test-branch-2</artifactId>
<version>1.0.21-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I want to remove `-SNAPSHOT` from this using maven in batch mode, so I can do it with Jenkins and not have to specify anything manually.

I've looked at the documentation for version:set but all the options offer me an interactive prompt and ask me to type a name for the version.

I would prefer the versions plugin, not the release plugin.

Comment: `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.21` should do the trick, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but no. How did you arrive at the string "1.0.21" without having less'ed or cat'ed or grep'ed the pom?

Comment: Ah, I see. Take a look at [page 123 f. of DevOps for Developers](http://books.google.de/books?id=yEqrMNX3LAgC&lpg=PA124&ots=IoIU0MYUp-&dq=huettermann%20automatic%20releasing&hl=de&pg=PA123#v=onepage&q=huettermann%20automatic%20releasing&f=false), Michael Hüttermann describes a Maven plugin that removes the -SNAPSHOT and sets the _newVersion_ property of the versions plugin accordingly.

Comment: I give up. I'm using the release plugin for now.

Comment: And it has to be all Maven? You could get the version via the help plugin -  mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version, but then you need some help of sed or something to remove the 'SNAPSHOT' suffix. Of course you might as well grep for the version directly.

Comment: Coming back to this, I want to say, understanding the maven release process was the right way to go; trying to fudge snapshot and release versions was wrong. Using the maven release plugin has taught me a lot.

Comment: @Jepper I added a new answer, which you may want to make the accepted answer (the one with `mvn versions:set -DremoveSnapshot`, not my older answer)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Since version 2.10 of the Versions Maven Plugin you can simply do:

```
mvn versions:set -DremoveSnapshot
```

Comment: Thanks for this one, that's the simplest solution !

Comment: @jeanMarcAssin Shouldn't this be the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes it should, but I'm not the OP so I can't change it. @Jepper did you tried Rinke solution ?

Comment: Works with plugin version 2.5. Doesn't work with plugin version 2.2. Don't know in between. Version 2.5 is the latest at time of writing.

Comment: Nice! Thanks so much. And if you use version control, dispense with that silly poor-person's backup mechanism: `mvn versions:set -DremoveSnapshot -DgenerateBackupPoms=false`

Comment: This is really weird, I tried to find that instruction in the documentation and I didn't find it... Do you have any reference for the documentation?

Comment: @JuanRamos https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html#removeSnapshot

Comment: @Radu works since 2.10, see  https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html#removeSnapshot

Answer (score 14):

If you really don't want to use the Maven Release Plugin (for whatever reason), here is how I succeed on dropping the SNAPSHOT suffix (hanbdled as a classifier) from a maven POM in a standard way (that is, no scripting, no custom maven plugin).

Given the following profile:

```
<profile>
    <id>drop-snapshot</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>parse-version</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>parse-version</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>set-version</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>set</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <newVersion>${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.incrementalVersion}</newVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>upgrade-pom</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>commit</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

And simply executing: `mvn validate -Pdrop-snapshot`
The version of an example pom passed from `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` to `0.0.1`.

How it actually works:

- The `build-helper-maven-plugin`, [`parse-version`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html) goal, will parse the current version of the POM and set it in a set of properties having by default `parsedVersion` as a prefix and `majorVersion`, `minorVersion`, `incrementalVersion` as suffixes (check the documentation, you will also have `classifier` and `buildNumber`). Hence, after its execution we can then use in our POM the properties like `${parsedVersion.majorVersion}` and so on.
- The `versions-maven-plugin`, [`set`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html) goal, will then use these properties to build the new version you actually want (in this case dropping the SNAPSHOT, because we excluded the `${parsedVersion.classifier}` property).
- Lastly, the `versions-maven-plugin`, [`commit`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/commit-mojo.html) goal, will make these changes effective.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <name>newVersion</name>
                <value>${project.version}</value>
                <regex>-SNAPSHOT</regex>
                <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You can now remove the `-SNAPSHOT` part of your project's version with:

```
mvn build-helper:regex-property versions:set -N
```

The `-N` tells Maven to only proces the root project in case you have modules defined in your POM. This is not strictly necessary but prevents the `build-helper` plugin from running unnecessarily against the submodules. The `versions` plugin runs only on the root project in any case, and traverses all modules automatically. Consider using the `reactorModuleConvergence` rule of the `maven-enforcer` plugin to make sure multi-module projects are handled correctly.

You can run `mvn versions:commit` to remove the backup POM(s) generated by `versions:set`. Alternatively you can add `<generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>` to the configuration of the `versions` plugin.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to A_Di-Matteo's approach with `build-helper`, but without the need for additional plugins configuration:

```
 mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
     -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion} \
         .\${parsedVersion.minorVersion} \
         .\${parsedVersion.incrementalVersion \
         .\${parsedVersion.buildNumber} \
      versions:commit
```

This will replace your `1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT` with `1.0.0.0` in the `pom.xml`.